# IBDesignable view not rendering

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have a simple `@IBDesignable` view that I have specified as the base class for the top level view in a scene in my macOS storyboard. For example:

```
@IBDesignable
class OvalView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NSColor.red.setFill()
        NSBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).fill()
    }
}
```

When I run the app, this view appears fine. But this designable view is not rendered in my scene in Interface Builder:

[image]

Note, this problem only manifests itself when the view in question is the top level view of the scene. If I do it for subviews, it works fine:

[image]

Comment: This is an older post but as of XCode 10.2.1, this now works.

Comment: Weird. It's definitely working for me. Both the color and brush sizes change when I  change those properties in IB's Inspector.

Comment: Unfortunately, I you misunderstood the question in this case, namely that the problem manifests itself only when dealing with the top-level view. The problem actually still persists in Xcode 10.2.1 and Xcode 11.

Comment: My apologies if I misunderstood 'top level view' - that could be taken in several different contexts. Does 'top level view' mean a NSViewControllers content view? e.g. on the storyboard, a window's viewControllers view? I am having a similar issue - just want to clarify.

Comment: See snapshots in the revised question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that Interface Builder does not appear to properly render a `@IBDesignable` macOS view in Interface Builder if that view is the top level view in a scene. It will in iOS, but not macOS. In macOS, it only renders the designable view in Interface Builder if it is a subview, but not the top level view.

I have filed a bug report. #27817119

Comment: I received update that this bug report was a duplicate of previous one. So, Apple is at least aware of the issue.

Comment: This bug still appears to exist in XCode 8.3 :(

Comment: Still here in Xcode 11.5 in June 2020. Slightly infuriating.