# Applying appropriate colors when switching appearance on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, appearance

I am trying to use semantic colors that are created like this:

[image]

And I have a custom class called ColoredView, that looks like this:

```
@IBDesignable class ColoredView: NSView {
    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor = .clear
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        backgroundColor.set()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }
}
```

and in Attributes Inspector I set this color for inspectable property background:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

(what I can only notice is that designables crashed in case of my custom color, but doesn't crash if I use system predefined semantic colors)

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: Designables error]

The thing is, after I switch theme with:

```
NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua) // .darkAqua/.aqua
```

only background color of a main view changes appropriately (also some text as I have noticed). How to solve this that my custom views follow appearance changes?

Comment: What does "How to solve this that my custom views follow appearance changes?" mean?

Comment: Just as in UIKit, an easy solution is use of `NSColor.Name` in Cocoa.

Comment: @ElTomato I mean, when I change appearance like explained above, that colors that I have made (each one has dark/light value) to be applied automatically... Or I should do it manually in this case?

Comment: Select the color profile you've created through Storyboard so that the system will automatically use either Any Appearance or Dark.

Comment: @ElTomato I did that, (its mentioned already in a question) and it didn't work. I will update a question to show you what I did

Comment: Actually, I don't have a problem.  It says 'Designables Up to date √.'

Comment: It looks like something is damaged. Have you tried restarting Xcode, Clean Build Folder or replacing the view? Is the issue reproducable in a new test project?

Comment: @Willeke I don't have a test project available. I tried clean Build project and restarting Xcode yes. I can try to replace a view...

Comment: @Willeke seems like this is a problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975988/ib-designable-class-not-rendering-on-interface-builder

Comment: Is the question about `IBDesignable` or about the color not changing at runtime?

Comment: Well generally about color not changing. I actually managed to do it. I had to explicitly set appearance on my custom views. Like `myColoredView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: ...)` After that, those views started using my custom colors.